# switching a 12v/2.5W pump with a atmega (relay)

Tags: atmega

I've got a "Seliger 280" water pump here with the following data:

12V, 2,5W

the supplied power supply can do 12V/1,2A.

But is also used to drive a 10W light bulb by default.

pump current:

\$ P = U \cdot I\$

\$I=\frac PU = \frac{2.5\,\text W}{12\,\text V}=208\,\text{mA}\$

Can I assume a ~2A start current (*10)?

The pump is immersed in water all the time, so it is basically stalled at start.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Zo2T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Calculating the base resistor:

relais: FTR‑B3SA4.5Z

```
145 Ω
4,5V
```

\$I=\frac UR = \frac{5\,\text V}{145\,\Omega}=34\,\text{mA}\$

Can a 4,5V relais handle 5V?

transistor: 2N2222A

dc current gain with Ic = ~34mA is 100

for saturation divide by 3. 100/3 = 33

Ib = Ic / hFE = 34mA / 33 = 1mA

Rb = 4.5V - 0.7V / ib = 3.8 / 1mA = 3,8kOhm

(assuming the atmega can at least provide 4,5V with 5V supply voltage)
0.7V is one diode drop between base and emitter

suggestions? errors?

Comment: The unit V is written with a capital V, as the stationary currents I, the stationary voltages U are written with a capital letter. My edit suggestion is in review queue.

Comment: review queue? what?
you could have written that theres no flyback diode in it...i mean, somtething usefull.

or that the transistor belongs below the relais...

but hey, capital letters make the circuit much more appealing..doesnt work...but it looks good and right.

just trolling for some points i guess...

Comment: I don't have the reputation points yet to directly edit your question. When I make edits, they go into a moderated queue of suggested edits. Mine were just approved a minute ago. See your modified question.

Comment: @JamesBaker: Your question was very sloppily written. This is an English language site and normal rules of capitalisation and punctuation apply with allowances for non-English speakers. Apart from making the post more difficult to read, the sloppy approach gives an unflattering impression (of you) to the reader. Marcus is correct about capitalisation of 'V' for "volt", etc. These are defined SI unit symbology. He doesn't get points for edits (as far as I know) so you may wish to retract your ill-mannered response.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ71oc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1a, b and c options.*

- (a) Use this configuration for a 5 V relay.
- (b) Use this configuration for a 12 V relay.
- (c) Use this configuration to avoid the relay.

> Can I assume a ~2A start current (*10)?

No. Measure the DC resistance of the motor at its terminals. From that you can calculate the stall current using Ohm's Law.

> \$ R_b = 4.5V - 0.7V / I_b = 3.8 / 1mA = 3,8~k\Omega\$.

That's correct but it's usually a good idea to overdrive the base to ensure that the transistor is fully on. Use 1k.

Comment: crap, i just realised that the power source provided does output 12V AC and not DC as i expected. 

i almost switched my design to use a mosfet, but now with the AC i would also need a optocopler to drive the mosfet right?

Comment: with AC your MOSFET won't be happy.

Answer (score -1):

> Can a 4,5V relais handle 5V?

Ask the datasheet! In general, if it was specified for 4.5V shouldn't be driven with 5V (well, that's what ratings are for?!).

However, considering your transistor will also have a voltage drop, you're probably OK. If in doubt, add a series resistor – your relais is specced to turn on with 3.38 V across it.

Other than that, the coil resistance most probably means "ohmic" resistance. Go for the power rating on how much current you can put through it:

\$\frac{80 \ldots 130\,\text{mW}}{4.5\ \text V} = 17\ldots28\,\text{mA}\$.

Suggestion here is clearly that for a pump that draws a maximum of 208 mA, you can quite definitely get rid of the relais. Just use the transistor in series with the pump (and use a diode in reverse, so you don't fry your transistor with the voltage spikes that will happen when you turn off your pump).

Comment: wouldnt the transistor be killed with the ~2A stall current?
the pump is immersed in water all the time.

Comment: Depends on your transistor! There is plenty transistors beefy enough. Alternatively, use a series resistor to limit the current.

Answer (score -1):

to not kill my first questions and make the comments seem out of place i i will answer my own question and hope its right.

what changed?
i need to switch 12V AC@2A
(2A being the worst case)

so new shematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5w4a0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

the flyback diode can handle 10A - its lying around.
Now theres no direct connection between the atmega and AC.